# Acumatica Endpoint How To setup so can expand Files

Tags: acumatica

I have a api endpoint setup looking at bill and adjustments (AP301000).  When I access the API and retrieve a single bill using the ids route parameter the json result gives me a list of the files associated with the bill.
Example

```
    "files": [
    {
        "id": "84eae2b3-eff3-4eaf-8de1-4cad8ee23aa7",
        "filename": "Bills and Adjustments (INV, 000338)\\file.pdf",
        "href": "dsafsdf"
    }
 ]
```

I want this list to be shown when I am getting multiple bills, but it does not show.  I tried to use the $expand=files query parameter but it cannot find the key.

Is this possible to do if so how can I do it?  Is there something extra I need to setup in the endpoint?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This request works for me:

```
{{url}}entity/Default/22.200.001/Bill?$expand=files
```

I tested it with version 18.200.001, and I got the key not found error message.

Comment: 18.200 is what I am using.  Ill test today with the higher version. Thanks

Comment: Yes works in 20.200.001. Thanks